# Haskell functions with parameters different types

Tags: function, haskell

As the questions states, I am having a little trouble with defining a function with parameters different types. (array of Num, two parameters Int and returning Int).

This is function title:

```
_sum_divide :: (Num a) => [a] -> (Int b) => b -> b -> b
```

And I get this error I cannot figure out

```
`Int' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `_sum_divide':
  _sum_divide :: Num a => [a] -> Int b => b -> b -> b
```

Sorry for the silly error, I am a noob with Haskell.

Thanks, have a good day/evening.

Comment: What is `Int b` supposed to be? And why do you have two constraint-arrows `=>`?

Comment: I actually don't really know 100% how constraint arrows work. a is supposed to be Num and b Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for a function that takes list of `Num`s and 2 int, and returns an int is:

```
_sum_divide :: (Num a) => [a] -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

The part before the thick arrow specifies the constraints. The part after it is where you use the constraints.

You had 2 main issues:

- There should only 1 list of constraints in a signature.
- `Int` isn't a Typeclass. `(Num a)` means `a` can be any type that supports the `Num` Typeclass. `Int` however is a concrete type, not a Typeclass, so `(Int b)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've helped me a lot to understand.

Comment: @Marcus No problem. Just a suggestion: since types are such a prominent feature in Haskell, and understanding the type system is crucial for understanding error messages, Id go back over and review type signatures if I were you. It's well worth the investment of time.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a basic confusion between the concepts of *type classes* and of *types*. OO languages throw these all together, but in Haskell they are fundamentally different things.

- A type is a *set<sup>†</sup> of values*. For example, the type `Bool` contains the values `False` and `True`. The type `Int` contains the values `0`, `1` ... `9223372036854775807` and their negatives.
- A type class is a *set of types*. For example, the class `Num` contains the type `Int`, the type `Double`, the type `Rational`... and whatever type `T` of your own, if you just define an `instance Num T`.

Generally, *types* are used in function signatures just by naming them. For instance,

```
foo :: [Int] -> [Int]
foo = map (*3)
```

is a function accepting a list of `Int` numbers (i.e. values of type `Int`), and gives another such list as the result (wherein each entry is tripled).

There is no constraint at all in the signature of `foo`. I could actually add one, like

```
foo :: Num Int => [Int] -> [Int]
```

This would express that the function needs `Int` to be an instance of the `Num` class to work. Well, it does need that in order to be able to calculate `*3`, but the constraint is superfluous, because we *know* that `Int` is a `Num` instance, the compiler doesn't just forget about that.

Where constraints are really useful is in *polymorphic* functions. For example, the following function triples every entry in a list of numbers, and *doesn't care what particular type the numbers have*:

```
foo :: Num n => [n] -> [n]
foo = map (*3)
```

This notation with *type variables* like `a` is actually shorthand for

```
foo :: ∀ n . Num n => [n] -> [n]
```

meaning, *for all numerical types `n`*, the function `foo` maps lists of `n`-values to lists of `n`-values.

It's important that constraints are completely separate<sup>‡</sup> from the actual type specification in a signature. For instance, to specify for a polymorphic function `[a] -> b -> b -> b` that `a` should be a `Num` instance and `b` an [`Integral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) instance (the class of whole-number types, containing amongst other `Int`), you'd write

```
sum_divide :: (Num a, Integral b) => [a] -> b -> b -> b
```

Alternatively, if you really mean `Int` – that's just a single type, no reason to introduce a *type variable* for it.

```
sum_divide :: Num a => [a] -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

...although, you *can* still introduce the `b` variable if you like. You'll need an *equational constraint* (those are basically ad-hoc type classes containing only a single type)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

sum_divide :: (Num a, b ~ Int) => [a] -> b -> b -> b
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Mathematicians would object about several levels of differences between *types*, *sets* and *classes*. Read my notion of “set” as just “collection of things”.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>In more complicated settings you can actually mix constraints and types, but that's advanced stuff.</sub>